# Laravel Nexmo SMS Notifications not sending

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sms, laravel-notification

I am trying to send SMS notifications using Nexmo in Laravel, I have been following the official [documentation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#sms-notifications).

For some reason my notifications do not send, but I don't get any errors at all.

I've set up my Notification class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Message\NexmoMessage;

class bookingAdded extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }


    /**
     * Get the Nexmo / SMS representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return NexmoMessage
     */
    public function toNexmo($notifiable)
    {
        return (new NexmoMessage)
                    ->content('Your SMS message content');
    }

}
```

In my `Booking` model I have added the `routeNotificationForNexmo()` method to customize the phone number the notification is delivered to:

```
namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

    class Booking extends Model
    {           
        use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Route notifications for the Nexmo channel.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function routeNotificationForNexmo()
    {
        $intl_number = preg_replace('/^07/','447', $this->customer_phone);
        return $intl_number;
    }

}
```

In my `BookingController` I am sending the actual SMS notification in my `update` method:

```
 /**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(BookingRequest $request, $id)
{       
        $booking = Booking::find($id);
        $booking->notify(new bookingAdded($booking))
}
```

When I update a record it saves without any errors at all, but I don't receive the sms. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The notifications are being stored in the database but the data is empty:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to queue the notifications?

Comment: No, I just want to send them on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that in the `via` method in the Notification class I had to set `nexmo` as the channel:

```
     /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['nexmo'];
    }
```

It would default to database, hence why I was getting records in my db. Now it sends the sms fine.

If you want to store the notifications in the database as well as send the sms through nexmo you can just return both channels:

```
return ['nexmo', 'database'];
```